# Unemployment analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, business-analyst

I have been tasked to make a map or some sort of analysis that analyzes the spatial relationship of a certain ethnic that has high unemployment to areas that have potential employment opportunities. Data that I have are: Current census data, employer point data, and unemployment data.

Is there any other data I might need and what arcmap extension is out there that I can use that will easily analyze the data or do I have to get ESRI Business Analyst?

Comment: What is your hypothesis? What is your research question? You may or may not have what you need, but it would help us to answer your question if you went into greater detail about your task.